# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to PHP's "or" operator?

Tags: javascript, php, syntactic-sugar

In PHP, you can use the "or" keyword to execute a function if the first expression evaluates to something falsey:

```
<?php
(1 == 2) or exit("error: 1 does not equal 2");
?>
```

Is there something similar in JavaScript that's a sweet one-liner like the PHP example?

The best I can come up with in JavaScript is a helper function, where argument 1 is the condition to evaluate, and argument 2 is either a string or function. If the argument 1 is false and argument 2 is a string, then the function will throw an error with the string as the error message. If argument 2 is a function, then the function will get executed:

```
<script>
function or(condition, err_msg_or_function) {
    if (typeof (condition) !== "boolean") {
        throw new Error("or error: argument 1 must be boolean");
    } else {
        if (!condition) {
            if (typeof (err_msg_or_function) === "function") {
                err_msg_or_function();
            } else if (typeof (err_msg_or_function) === "string") {
                throw new Error(err_msg_or_function);
            } else {
                throw new Error("or error: argument 2 must be a function or a string");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In practice:

```
<script>
or((1 == 2), "error: 1 does not equal 2");
</script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `true === false || console.log('something like that?')`

Comment: @Jeto roblox oof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1 == 2) || alert("error: 1 does not equal 2");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into the [Online Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical

Answer (score 0):

```
false === true || document.write('By using this we can perform the same thing with PHP')



(1===1) === (2===2) || document.write('we can replace the booleans by operators')
```

Try This if you are looking for something like this...

Answer (score 0):

something || another

(1 == 2) || "error: 1 does not equal 2"